# Graphing time series in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, time-series

I'm new to R and am having a lot of trouble with what's essentially my first assignment.
I'm trying to plot the adjusted closing prices of the NASDAQ over a time period 2014-2018 (time series analysis module).

I have been provided with the following code which I am told I should have to make minor adjustments to:

```
data <- read.csv('Nasdaq_2014_2018.csv')

t <- data[,1]    #This is the date (yyyy-mm-dd), first column of the dataset
y <- data[,6]    #This is the adjusted closing price, sixth column of the dataset

plot(t, y)
```

The error messages I am getting are:

```
error in data[,1]: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
error in data[,6]: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

and

```
error in plot.function(t,y): object 'y' not found
```

I find this last one strange as `t` seems to  exist. I have tried other methods to plot the graph to no avail, i.e

```
plot(Nasdaq_2014_2018$Date, Nasdaq_2014_2018$Adj.Close)
```

I understand this may be a very basic question but I've been trying to fix the problem all day to no avail, and this is only the first part of the first question of the assignment :(

Comment: Hard to tell. From the famous "error in data[,1]: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" error message I would guess that the code line `data <- read.csv('Nasdaq_2014_2018.csv')` failed´, e.g. because the file was not found or ... Maybe you could check that by running this line again.

Comment: Yes I just ran the first line there and it appears to be (part) of the problem. I'll try amend it now - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would have a look at the `xts` package that was developed for TS in the context of Trading and Stocks. `dplyr` whith `lubridate` for the date might be more complex in your case.
Regarding importing as you stuck have a look at the other import functions.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("QQQ", auto.assign = T)

plot(QQQ$QQQ.Adjusted)
```

Using your data:

```
library(xts)

dataxts <- xts(data[, -1], order.by = as.Date(data[, 1], format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
plot.xts(dataxts[, 5])
```